# Gmail attach file keyboard shortcut

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, gmail

I would like to know if there is any keyboard shortcut to attach a file when writing an email.

Most of the shortcuts can be found [here](http://www.shortcutworld.com/en/web/Gmail.html), but they do not include any for this task.

Comment: If you enable keyboard shortcuts in Settings > General, then you can view "all" the available shortcuts in a popup tooltip by hitting `?`. However, it seems this is not quite "all" of them, as I noticed that the shortcut to pull up the emoticon menu (`Ctrl`+`Shift`+`2`) is not listed (but this is stated in the tooltip for the menu button itself). There is nothing documented for the "attach files" option.

Comment: The `Shift+?` is a great trick! Thanks! But in the compose email window it doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: (Whilst on most keyboards you have to hit `Shift` to get `?`, the shortcut is literally just `?`.) Yes, it doesn't work when _focus_ is on the "compose" window, however, the popup that displays when in the main window (when focus is moved away from the compose window) contains all the same (compose and chat) shortcuts. However, as mentioned, there is nothing listed for "attach files" and a few random key combos hasn't revealed any hidden wonders for me unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks @w3d, I will send a feedback proposal to Gmail and let's hope for the best!

Comment: This is the best we may have, thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There's no a specific shortcut, however, while composing the body of the email, hit <kbd>Tab</kbd> three times. (The first hit moves you to the `SEND` button, the second one moves you to the `Schedule Send` arrow, and the third one takes you to the clip icon for attachments.) Bam! Now you're able to paste the path for your attachment.

Answer (score -1):

CTRL + O is the shortcut key for Attachment in gmail.

Comment: Doesn't work on my machine, unfortunately. Do you have any reference for this?

Comment: -1 : Ctrl+o is the shortcut for open a file in the browser. So this answer is for the garbage collector.